# Divide One Column by Another with Time Lag

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table storing stock prices, i.e. stock ID, date, open price, close price. I want to select a table within a certain date range, and also comes with the price returns from yesterday's close to today's open.

Basically I need to add a column, where the value for ith row equals Open(i)/Close(i-1), how can I do it?

I know if easy to calculate Open(i)/Close(i), but how to divide with a value from a different row? The length of the new column will be 1 unit less than the length of other columns, is it possible to put an 'NA' in order to match the length?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Gordon it's simple `2017-05-01`,`ABC`,'100$'  and `2017-05-02`,`ABC`,`105$`
So he wants another column while selecting and it's value were  `2017-05-02`,`ABC`,`105$`,'105/100'

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I meant. Does anyone knows how to do it in one step? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, the [lag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) function can be used to retrieve values from other rows, like so:

```
Select
[stock_id],
[date],
[open]/LAG([close],1) OVER (PARTITION BY [stock_id] ORDER BY [date] asc) as [return]
from tbl_1
ORDER BY [stock_id],[date]
```

This will also automatically NULL the first date in the series, where it is not possible to calculate the return.

Comment: Thanks Kit, this is very helpful!

Comment: That's OK Aaron, does it answer your question?